# Взнос за капремонт или взнос на капремонт?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Взнос за капремонт или взнос на капремонт?

Comment: Будьте добры, следите за корректностью меток, задавая вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Заплатить *за капремонт* можно только по *полной* его смете (заранее или по окончании).

Взносы же **на**правляются **на** цели капремонта *частями* от полной его стоимости, поэтому "**на капремонт**".

Answer (score 1):

На капремонт - есле взнос платится авансом, то есть, перед работой, за капремонт - если работа уже проделана.  Сравните: заработная плата - плата уже заработана. Сбор денег на шторы, на мебель, на капремонт - сбор на то, что предстоит приобрести, проделать.